# Radio button in react does not respond

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a simple SignUp form in a DRF-React app  which contains two radio buttons but the data I am receiving in serializers is always false for those two radio buttons

**Serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializerWithToken(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    token = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    # remember_me = serializers.BooleanField()


    def get_token (self, obj):
        jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
        jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

        payload = jwt_payload_handler(obj)
        token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)
        return token

    def create (self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)  
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)

        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('token', 'username', 'password','is_teacher', 'is_supplier')
```

Serializers.data

```
{'token': 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyNiwidXNlcm5hbWUiOiI4OTg5IiwiZXhwIjoxNTY0NjUyMTU4LCJlbWFpbCI6ZmFsc2V9.LoqDM31Zh95y0llUqFgeM9n7VC27gYDTXeSjVukFJdw', 
'username':'8989', 

'is_teacher': True, 'is_supplier': True}
```

**SignupForm.js**

```
    class SignupForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
    type: '',
  };

  handle_change = e => {
    const name = e.target.name;
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState(prevstate => {
      const newState = { ...prevstate };
      newState[name] = value;
      console.log(newState);
      return newState;

    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={e => this.props.handle_signup(e, this.state)}>
        <h4>Sign Up</h4>
        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          value={this.state.username}
          onChange={this.handle_change}
        />
        <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          value={this.state.password}
          onChange={this.handle_change}
        />
        <label htmlFor="type">User type</label>
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="is_teacher"             #Change 1
          value="1"
          // checked={this.state.type == "1"}
          onChange={this.handle_change}
        />Shipper
        <input
          type="radio"
          name="is_supplier"                       #Change 2
          value="1"
          // checked={this.state.type == "1"}
          onChange={this.handle_change}
        />Supplier
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default SignupForm;

SignupForm.propTypes = {
  handle_signup: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};
```

**Views.py**

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def current_user (request):

    serializer = UserSerializer(request.user)
    return Response(serializer.data)


class UserList(APIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post (self, request, format=None):
        self.http_method_names.append("GET")

        serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(data=request.data)


        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            print("serializer data is", serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What is that I am doing wrong ? Shouldn't I receive 1 in seriailizer.data when I click on the radio button ?

**Edit**
Now I am able to save response of radio buttons but I can mark both of them which is wrong, how do I restrict that ?

Answer (score 0):

`const value = e.target.value;` should be `const value = e.target.checked` for radio input.

Comment: but that auto populates "false" in username

Comment: I edited the question, now I am able to save response of radio buttons but I can mark both of them which is wrong, how do I restrict that ?

Comment: You need to give them the same name.